# IIS with multiple sites with different ports

Tags: windows, dns, ip, iis, web

I have a windows server and IIS instance that have a default website on port 80 and a domain set to this server IP, now I want to point another domain to this IP and DNS provider said you can not set the domain to IP with port and must be configured with just IP, now when people call my second domain, requests will go on 80 port and my first website will open,
what is the solution?

sample1.com point to this IP: x.x.x.x
sample2.com also point to this IP: x.x.x.x
now in IIS, I want to handle the request of first domain to my site with port 80 and second domain to open my website with port 81 in IIS

Comment: I'd use SNI if its HTTPS, and probably MS URL Rewite 2.0 if I was in your position. DNS will not solve your issue, as it cannot direct traffic to ports. with SNI you wouldn't even have to host on a different port, but it does seem like you are using HTTP over 80 so url rewriting is probably your best bet. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: @FrankThomas 
a great solution, Thanks